# How does the tor user agent change? resolved

Tags: node.js, tor

I use node.js to make requests on google.

I used puppeteer but he detected my robot.

so i used tor-request.

I can change my ip at each connection.

But google still hangs with the same error message.

I want to change the user-agent of the tor-expert bundle.

How to do ?

> Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network.
>   Please try your request again later. Why did this happen?
>
> IP address: 109.70.100.** Time: 2019-08-03T08:47:17Z URL:
>   https://www.google.com/search?q=re&gbv=1&sei=6UlFXY6mKsSiab3EjbAF

```
var tr = require('tor-request');
tr.TorControlPort.password = "***";
io.sockets.on('connection', async(socket) => {
    socket.on('key', function(value) {
    function torIp() {
            tr.request('https://www.google.com/search?q=re&gbv=1&sei=6UlFXY6mKsSiab3EjbAF', function(error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    console.log("Your public IP is: " + body);
                }
                socket.emit('google_web', body)
            });
        }
        torIp();
        tr.renewTorSession(function(error, msg) {
            console.log(error);
            console.log(msg);
            if (msg) {
                torIp();
            }
        });
    })
})
```

Comment: It's likely due to the fact that many other Tor users using the same exit node have Googled things too many times, resulting in a temporary block for that IP. Probably not something you can fix on your side. (maybe try a less-used search engine?)

Comment: I have no problem with other search engines.
However, I would like to work around this problem for Google.

all nodes are blocked on google.
I think the problem comes from the user-agent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the user agent, you can use the method described [here](https://github.com/talmobi/tor-request/issues/13), a tor-request issue:

```
tr.request({
  url: 'https://www.google.com/search?q=re&gbv=1&sei=6UlFXY6mKsSiab3EjbAF',
  headers: {
    'user-agent': 'giraffe'
  }
}, function(error, response, body) {
  // ...
});
```

Just replace `giraffe` with whichever user agent you wish.

(But, as the comment noted, Google may well have blocked certain Tor exit nodes completely, in which case changing the user-agent won't help)

Comment: OK, thanks,
it worked from time to time.
google have block too much ip ..